# Typeahead source not getting updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead.js

Typeahead source not getting updated if user types in the textbox then clears it, then again start typing in it

Here is my code

```
<input id="docSearch" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search Doctor..."  >

$('#docSearch').keyup(function(){                  
    var list;
    var q = $('#docSearch').val();
    if(!q){
        return;
    }
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "pullDocs.php",
        data: {inp:q},
        success: function(data){
            //Typeahead accepts only proper json
            list = $.parseJSON(data);
            $('#docSearch').typeahead({
                source: list
            })
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed my js code(Just replaced the keyup function) as below, then it worked well

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#docSearch').typeahead({
        source: function (query, result) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "pullDocs.php",
                data: 'inp=' + query,            
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: function (data) {
                    result($.map(data, function (item) {
                        return item;
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```